# Cannot assign onClick to a button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick

I am working on an android studio project which is partially built in kotlin and the rest in in java. I have never worked with kotlin before this project and currently I have found myself spending hours trying to implement a simple onclick to a button. I know this question has been asked a lot but most of the solutions I have tried do not work.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/folioPageFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/indicatorLayout">

    <com.folioreader.ui.view.WebViewPager
        android:id="@+id/webViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.folioreader.ui.view.FolioWebView
        android:id="@+id/folioWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<com.folioreader.ui.view.LoadingView
    android:id="@+id/loadingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:maxVisibleDuration="10000"
    tools:visibility="invisible" >
</com.folioreader.ui.view.LoadingView>

<com.folioreader.ui.view.VerticalSeekbar
    android:id="@+id/scrollSeekbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/indicatorLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="655dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonVasko"
        android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/indicatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minutesLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:textSize="7sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pagesLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
        android:textSize="8sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the beginning of the onCreateView function:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    buttonVasko.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view:View) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"WORK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }// end onClick
    })
```

this is the error I receive when running the code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.folioreader.android.sample, PID: 3862
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method zoko(View) in a 
parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view 
class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buttonVasko'
```

I also tried placing the setOnClickListener at the very end in the onCreateView function in case there was a line of code that needed to be written before the setOnClickListener but the result is the same.

Full FolioPageFragment is here:
https://codeshare.io/5PlwDw

Comment: Your button doesn't have any id. Are you sure you're assign onClick listener to right button ?

Comment: buttonVasko is the id (for now), I'm assigning the onClick directly.

Comment: This is a fragment or activity? Because on summary you say onCreate, but in code block you have onCreateView

Comment: Yes it is a fragment. My mistake in the wording there. Will change it.

Comment: Can you try to assign onClick listener in onViewCreated function?

Comment: Ok. you need to look for the button on the fragment view. Its not same as activity which creates your bindings after you setContentView. So you have the `inflatedView.buttonVasko.setOnClickListener`

Comment: There is no onViewCreated function. inflatedView is an unresloved reference.

Comment: Can you add your all fragment class?

Comment: you have not inflated layout

Comment: @VaskoVasilev I have edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: If nothing worked already I think it's better to paste your entire fragment code

Comment: Entire fragment code is to share in a post. What is the best way to upload it as a file?

Comment: You can just copy and paste

Comment: It goes over the maximum character limit.

Comment: How long is your Fragment? :D You can shorten some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already inflate your fragment as mRootView. You can set your onClick listener in onViewCreated. Here is the code

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonVasko).setOnClickListener {

    }
}
```

And you should delete this static view imports.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.folio_page_fragment.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.folio_page_fragment.view.*
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yup, this is what was needed. I didn't delete
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.folio_page_fragment.view.*. as it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
    buttonVasko.setOnClickListener {
       // your code
Toast.makeText(context,"WORK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Comment: The same problem appears with this as well.

Answer (score -1):

As from discussion and comments, I can see that you are using a fragment. Fragment does not behave same as activity, it does not bind views by id like activity does when you `setContentView`. In your `onCreateView` when you inflate your fragment view, you need to look for views within that view:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false)
    view.buttonVasko.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "WORK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    return view
}
```

Comment: how does the second option differ from mine?

Comment: This is wrong. You cannot override onClick inside a lambda

Comment: This does not crash anymore, but the toast does not appear.